# how to set navigationBar color by calling a method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, subclassing

I created a CommonMethod subclass of NSObject for customizing UINavigationBar here is the CommonMethod.h and CommonMethod.m files

**CommonMethod.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface CommonMethods : NSObject
+(void)setNavBackButton:(id)viewController;
+(void)setNavBackground:(id)viewController Color:(UIColor *)color;
@end
```

**CommonMethod.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CommonMethods.h"
@implementation CommonMethods
+(void)setNavBackground:(id)viewController Color:(UIColor *)color
{
    UIViewController *controller = (id)viewController;
    controller.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
}
@end
```

Now when I am calling `[CommonMethods setNavBackground:self Color:[UIColor redColor];` it is executing the method but didn't change anything on UI. Can anyone expalin this what I am missing ?

Edit :

I also tried `controller.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = color;`

Comment: Where you have call this method ?

Comment: once controller.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor=[UIColor redColor]

Comment: @srinivasn I called this method in viewdidload and yes I also tried `controller.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor=[UIColor redColor]`

Comment: Put the Break point and check view controller object coming this method are not , once call the method in viewwillappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have minor Mistake on Code

```
+(void)setNavBackground:(id)viewController Color:(UIColor *)color
{
    UIViewController *controller = (id)viewController;
    controller.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = color; // Change NavigationBar color to Red
}
```

Call Method like this:[CommonMethod setNavBackground:self Color:[UIColor redColor]];

[image]

Comment: @VarunNaharia can you please tell me you can just change navigation bar color? if yes then it's work fine in my side.

Comment: @VarunNaharia you want to change color like this?

Comment: @VarunNaharia how to show navigation bar in your app can you please send me that code?

Comment: @VarunNaharia so my code is right brother. please check it again.

Comment: What do you mean by that ? It is added by navigationController

Comment: @VarunNaharia [UINavigationBar appearance]setBarTintColor:[UIColor RedColor]]; [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; use this code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in delegate class